# S3 - Redirect to a static website using a POST request

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I am hosting a static website on S3 and this is my form that redirects to this website.
I don't need to get any of the submitted parameters, just a simple redirect.

```
        <form action="http://website.com" method="POST"  >
          // my code
        </form>
```

After submitting the form, I am redirected to the static website but I had this error:

```
405 Method Not Allowed
Code: MethodNotAllowed
Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
Method: POST
ResourceType: OBJECT
RequestId: 1EEFE221F692910D
HostId: obKOVc3LTyhc4NUdrs+S7DXOOv6FZYmdWEXOgCo3UVdb6beiI/aP8bQxihaMUenYTJyE+thrCaQ=
```

My S3 bucket CORS configuration is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>    
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

While it seems that my CORS configuration are right, I don't still find from where comes the error message (405 Method Not Allowed).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a form to "redirect," use `<form ... method="GET">`.

You can't submit a `POST` request to an S3 website hosting endpoint.  It would serve no purpose, so it isn't allowed.

`405 Method Not Allowed` is *always* the response -- this can't be changed.